# Jenkins setup to work with different projects managed with the repo tool

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, yocto, repo

The main repository of my project is a manifest repository. This repository is downloaded with the "repo init" command. It downloads a manifest.xml pointing to three different projects: P1, P2 and P3. Each one of this three projects is a git repository downloaded with "repo sync" command. All of them are meta-layers of a Yocto project.

I want to create a Jenkinsfile to automate the build and testing of my Yocto project with Jenkins.

My question is: which is the proper place to store the Jenkinsfile? I see three options:

```
1) Inside the manifest repo
2) Inside one of the existing repositories (P1, P2 or P3).
3) Create a P4 repo just for the Jenkinsfile (and add P4 to the manifest.xml)
```

I don't like any of the three options. Option number 1 is poisoning the manifest repo (is just for the repo tool). Option number 3 implies creating a new repository just for the Jenkinsfile. That's not very useful. Finally, option number 2 implies storing a file into a repository that do not has any relationship with the content of that repository at all.

Can you suggest some alternative to organize this setup in the most convenient way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm planned to do 1. And push the generated manifest ro it too with the build_id as git tag.

Comment: If you have multiple of such projects I would recommend you to make a new repo for all your jenkinsfiles. You can call dem like projectA.jenkinsfile, projectB.jenkinsfile and so on.

Comment: Create a subfolder, e.g. 'tools' or 'scripts', and put it there.